# RFID antenna and LoRa module/flex antenna on the same PCB

Tags: pcb, antenna, rfid, lora

I need to place LoRa module on the PCB I designed. There is already an RFID antenna on this PCB that I designed before, and it is not possible to change its location.

Is the distance between LoRa module/antenna and RFID antenna important? Should I place the LoRa module and flex antenna farthest from the RFID antenna?

Flex antenna has U.FL connector and cable length is 10cm. So I can position it away from the PCB. In this case, can I position the LoRa module close to the RFID antenna?

Comment: Hard to answer without any pictures, but in general it shouldn't be much of a concern since they operate on quite different frequencies. That being said, keeping the antennas as far apart if possible is of course not a bad idea. In particular, avoid placing them "in parallel" with each other (or in parallel to anything metallic in general).

Comment: I apologize for not posting a photo. The RFID antenna I designed on the PCB covers almost half of the PCB. Considering other components, there is not much space for the LoRa module. That's why I wanted to ask such a question. This PCB will be in a plastic box and I will glue the flex antenna to the inner wall of the plastic box. So the distance between the RFID antenna and the LoRa antenna will be far.